# Libpcan study sources

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Respected,
I need to work on the concept of "libpcan". It is an entirely new topic and the possible sources i have found so far from where i can know and learn about this are as follows:
http://wiki.ros.org/libpcan

http://www.care-o-bot.de/en/research.html (not sure whether the latter link will help me or not).

When i try to implement the "libpcan" from the link "http://wiki.ros.org/libpcan", i get the following error on using the command "sudo ./install_pcan.sh"

[image: image description]

I am new to this field of libpcan and i am getting too many doubts and errors on this.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254750/libpcan-study-sources/) by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-02-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-17**:
This question already has an answer that isn't related to build issues, and in general other users don't look at questions that are answered. Please post your build issue as a new question.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-02-17**:
I tried but i failed to find the relevant solution. Probably some are present but are related to bring changes in the xml files to remove the error.
Unfortunately, i am unable to link them with my issue.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-02-17**:
In case you have the sol. ,kindly let me know. I am trying to get started with any possible code with libpcan and other can drivers, but still unable to implement a basic "libpcan" reference section on ros site. If you have the solution, or u know the link to the solution, do let me know.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

libpcan is a library for interacting with CAN interfaces from Peak System. There are many versions of the driver that are repackaged for ROS, but the original version comes directly from Peak System, and I would start with their documentation: http://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/index.htm

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-02-16**:
Thank you for the response sir.
But there are soo many driver versions to be read and downloaded. Being a beginner in this field, it is very tough for me start with an appropriate driver, can you help me which driver to begin with? Also, none driver has any code to implement.KIndly help me.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-16**:
Presumably you have some reason or requirements for wanting to use libpcan; you should be able to use those reasons to figure out which version to use (or just use the latest version).

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-16**:
I'm not sure which version of libpcan you're looking at, but it looks like version 8.3.1 of includes the source code for the library and the driver.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-02-16**:
Respected,
This could be an absurd beginning for libpcan. But i just need to start with a version ( i do not know which version will suit me) on which i can find readily avalaible example codes on the net so that i can gsin basic knowledge to understand its implementation.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-02-16**:
Since you have a lot more experience on this concept, it would be good for me to follow whichever version and source you will suggest to me.
Regards

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-16**:
You asked "where is the source for libpcan" and I knew the answer, so I answered. I don't use libpcan much myself, and you haven't mentioned any of your requirements for using it, so I cannot suggest a version.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-16**:
If you want official advice about which version of libpcan to use for your application, I suggest you contact Peak System directly.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-02-17**:
ok sir. thank you for replying.
Regards